# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W^{-n}}{1+\exp\left(\frac{W-\alpha}{\beta}\right)} dW$ with $0<n<1$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to integrate the function $$\frac{W^{-n}}{1+\exp\left(\frac{W-\alpha}{\beta}\right)}$$ with $0<n<1$ and limits between $0$ and $\infty$

I've initially tried plotting the [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOkvE.png) for two different values of $\alpha$ and $n=1/8$, to see if I could find a easily integrable function which fits the integrand but unsuccessful in this approach.

Next I'm trying to approximate the [numerator and denominator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELpjG.png) separately with function which I could integrate. This is where I'm stuck at the moment.

It would be helpful in guiding me towards some books or techiniques to approach this integral.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-n} dx}{(1+ge^{x/b})}, c=a/b, g=e^{-c} \implies I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ x^{-n} e^{-x/b}dx}{1+g^{-1} e^{-x/b}}.$$
Let $y=x/b$, then $$I=- b^{1-n}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} y^{-n} (-g^{-1})^ke^{-ky} dy= -b^{1-n} \Gamma(1-n) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-g^{-1})^k }{k^{1-n}}.$$ $$\implies I =-b^{1-n}~ \Gamma(1-n) ~Li_{(1-n)}(-e^{a/b})~~if~~ n <1. $$
Here $Li_{p}(z)$ is polylog function.